# What is differences between ResultSet and an object?

Tags: perl, resultset, dbix-class

From [DBIx::Class::ResultSet](http://search.cpan.org/~abraxxa/DBIx-Class-0.08209/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm) we read that:

```
WARNING
If called on an object, proxies to "new_result" instead, so
my $cd = $schema->resultset('CD')->new({ title => 'Spoon' });
will return a CD object, not a ResultSet, and is equivalent to:
my $cd = $schema->resultset('CD')->new_result({ title => 'Spoon' });
```

Could someone explain what is differences between object and ResultSet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is about the difference between calling `new` on a ResultSet *object* and the ResultSet *class name*. If you want to create a new ResultSet object using the ResultSet constructor, call `new` on the ResultSet package:

```
my $resultset = DBIx::Class::ResultSet->new(...);
```

(Although you typically don't have to create ResultSet objects this way.) If you call `new` on a ResultSet object, you won't get a new ResultSet object but a corresponding result (row) object:

```
my $row = $resultset->new(...);
```

Many other Perl classes make no difference whether `new` is called on the class name or an object of the class, hence the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the DBIx::Class::ResultSet docs:

> DBIx::Class::ResultSet - Represents a query used for fetching a set of results. A ResultSet is an object which stores a set of conditions representing a query.

A ResultSet is a specific object which represent a query. An object (not a ResultSet Object) is a single entity from the tables defined in the DBIx.

Lets say you have a DB of fathers and sons, one to many (each father can have many sons). So a single father in the DBIx context is an object, and so does a son. But the query "which father has a son named James" is a ResultSet Object.